# Download, install, configure, use spark packages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark/PySpark.  I was trying to read a CSV and attempted to use the spark-csv package that I keep seeing referenced by finding the .jar files, downloading, running "spark-submit --jars JARFILE pythoncode.py", it took forever to run and in the end after a df.show(), it displayed the headers sans data.   So compared to the function I wrote, it's slow and doesn't really work (I'm sure it's a mistake on my end).   I also tried to use the spark-ts package in sort of a similar way, but I cannot even get that to run.   Is there something like a pip install for Spark and/or any kind of baby step instructions for general Spark package installation/usage?

Comment: Can you give an example of how exactly you used spark-csv?